# Read date from bootstrap-datepicker in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, .net, datepicker

I have an asp.NET .NET Framework (forms) project
and I'm using a bootstrap-datepicker

```
<div class="border rounded" style="margin-bottom: 20px; border-radius: 2rem!important;">
   <p class="text-center">Birthday</p>
   <div class="form-label-group">

       <div style="margin-left: 23%; width: 52%; border-radius: 1rem!important;" id="txtDate" class="border rounded" runat="server"></div>
   </div>
</div>
```

This is the code for the datepicker and it's styling. Now In the .cs file I'm trying to read out the data from the `txtDate` element.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('[id*=txtDate]').datepicker({
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true,
            format: "dd/mm/yyyy",
            language: "tr"
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Does my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60692200/5519709) solve you problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can not get `DatePicker` value from code behind directly since the code is being run on the client side.

However you can do this by adding [`HiddenField`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.hiddenfield) and set value of this hidden field when `DatePicker` is updated:

So first add `HiddenField` to page:

```
<asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="hdnDate" />
```

Then implement [`dateChanged`](https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/events.html#changedate) event for DatePicker:

```
$(function () {

    $('[id*=txtDate]').datepicker({
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        format: "dd/mm/yyyy",
        language: "tr",

    })
    .change(dateChanged)
    .on('changeDate', dateChanged);

    function dateChanged(ev) {
        var dateValue = $('[id*=txtDate]').val();
        $("#<%= hdnDate.ClientID %>").val(dateValue);

    }

});
```

And let say we have button like this:

```
 <asp:Button ID="btnTest" Text="text" runat="server" OnClick="btnTest_Click" />
```

Finally, you can access date value via hidden field with `hdnDate.Value` in button click:

```
protected void btnTest_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CultureInfo provider = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
    DateTime dateValue = DateTime.ParseExact(hdnDate.Value, "dd/mm/yyyy", provider);
}
```